# How can I use registers in CtrlP?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I want to use vim registers in CtrlP input form, like `<C-r>"`.

`<C-r>` is used by `ToggleRegex()` by default.
So I configure CtrlP with g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings. like that,

```
let g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings = {
\ 'ToggleRegex()': ['<C-g>'],
\}
```

Then it seems to make effect, but error occur with pressing `<C-r>`.

```
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You should ask on CtrlP's issue tracker.

Answer (score 7):

it looks like you need `<c-\>` it opens a console dialog to paste `<cword>`, `<cfile>`, the content of the search register, the last visual selection, the clipboard or any register into the prompt.